# How to run the GUI file.exe in docker windows containers?

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I am trying to run the GUI(file.exe) application in the docker container. Is there any possibility to run the GUI in the background in the containers.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that is not (yet) possible.
Windows containers are mainly for IIS apps or .Net based services (Like linux containers in fact but this is often less sensitive as Linux services are meant to be GUI less).

I know this is a much awaited feature that is available if you run a Windows Insider preview but i didn't have the time to review it yet.

There is also the possibility to use some hacks that can be useful but i would keep for non production uses : https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde